# conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'Employee' requested

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
    /*These are attributes of a Employee class*/
    
    public:
    string Name;
    string Company;
    int Age;
    
    /*This is a method of class*/
    
    void IntroduceYourself()
    {
        cout<<"Name - "<< Name << endl;
        cout<<"Company - "<< Company << endl;
        cout<<"Age - "<< Age << endl;
    }
    
    /*This is user-defined constructor of class*/
    
    Employee (string name, string company, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Company = company;
        Age = age;
    }
    
};

int main ()
{
    /*Creating 1st instance of Employee class*/
    
    Employee employee1 = ("Danish", "Amazon" , 22);
    employee1.IntroduceYourself();
    
    /*Creating 2nd instance of Employee class*/
    
    Employee employee2 = ("Aqib", "Accountancy" , 23);
    employee2.IntroduceYourself();
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that when writing `("Danish", "Amazon" , 22)` you're using the built in [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) whcih will evaluate the fist two operands and then discard them and the final result of the expression `("Danish", "Amazon" , 22)` will be an `int` prvalue. But since there is no converting constructor in your class that takes an `int`, that final resulting `int` cannot be used to create `employee1`. Similarly, for `employee2` also.

The correct way to create the instances would be as shown below:

```
int main ()
{
   
//-----------------------v-----------------------v---->use braces instead of parenthesis
    Employee employee1 = {"Danish", "Amazon" , 22};
    employee1.IntroduceYourself();
    
    
//-----------------------v--------------------------v---->use braces instead of parenthesis    
    Employee employee2 = {"Aqib", "Accountancy" , 23};
    employee2.IntroduceYourself();
    
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/yFkCHEfHr)

##### Method 2

Use **direct initialization**.

```
int main ()
{
    //use direct initialization syntax
    Employee employee1("Danish", "Amazon" , 22);
    employee1.IntroduceYourself();
    
    //use direct initialization
    Employee employee2("Aqib", "Accountancy" , 23);
    employee2.IntroduceYourself();  
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/7rqKVROH3)